# Can you please help me solve this circuit?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, resistance, current-measurement

[image: electric circuit with a CCCS, one current source, one voltage source and three resistors]

So I'm trying to solve for \$V_n\$.
the way I solved it is by:
$$4I_x5+ 15I_x+ 5I_x= 15$$
$$I_x= \frac{15}{40}$$
then \$v_n= 7.5\$
What do i do wrong ?

Comment: Are you assuming that the current through the horizontal 5 ohm resistor is equal to *Ix*? If so, why?

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's solve this mathematically. We have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuOnmy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
0=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_2+\text{k}\cdot\text{I}_2=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_2\left(1+\text{k}\right)\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\text{I}_\text{x}+\text{I}_3\\
\\
0=\text{I}_\text{i}+\text{I}_3+\text{k}\cdot\text{I}_2\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{i}=\text{I}_\text{x}+\text{I}_1
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{R}_3}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
0=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}\cdot\left(1+\text{k}\right)\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}=\text{I}_\text{x}+\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
0=\text{I}_\text{i}+\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{R}_3}+\text{k}\cdot\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{i}=\text{I}_\text{x}+\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, we can solve for \$\text{V}_1\$:

$$\text{V}_1=\frac{\text{R}_1\left(1+\text{k}\right)\left(\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{I}_\text{x}\text{R}_3\right)}{\text{R}_1\left(1+\text{k}\right)+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3}\tag4$$

> Using your values, I got:
>
> $$\text{V}_1=-\frac{35}{2}=-17.5\space\text{V}\tag5$$

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, especially for the explanation why!